# how to use InputField function within the manipulate function

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, inputfield

I am trying to make a demonstration that can take in a matrix and create a vector field. Currently I have the demonstration all functioning but to define the matrix it uses sliders. I know they cannot be used to to define strings within manipulate but numbers can. if possible it would be nice to be able to put the inputfields in a 2x2 grid. currently I have:

```
Manipulate[value[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i],
 Style["Matrix values", 12, Bold],
 {a, -10, 10, 1},
 {b, -10, 10, 1},
 {c, -10, 10, 1},
 {d, -10, 10, 1},
 {{e, -10, "x-min"}, -20, 0, 1},
 {{f, 10, "x-max"}, 0, 20, 1},
 {{g, -10, "y-min"}, -20, 0, 1},
 {{h, 10, "y-max"}, 0, 20, 1},
 {{i, 5, "Solutions"}, 0, 50, 1}]
```

I would like a,b,c,d to be input boxes so I can put in a 2x2 matrix. If anyone could help that would be great. I think it would use InputField Function and the Dynamic function.
THANKS!!!

---

Ok, so I have figured one big thing out. instead of:

```
{a,-10,10,1}
```

(this defines a slider of range -10 to 10 with a step of 1)
replace the numbers with InputField

```
{a,InputField}
```

and then you can replace a with different names and a value seen on my e-i variables
I still can't find out how to make it look like a 2x2 matrix.

a  b

c  d

instead of 
a

b

c

d

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

coaxing `Manipulate` to do what you want seems to be a bit of a black art.  Perhaps there is cleaner way but this seems to work..

```
 Clear[a,b,c,d];
 Manipulate[
      m=Map[#[[1]] &, First@(List @@ matrix), {2}];
      MatrixForm@m,
        {matrix, 
          Grid[Map[InputField[Dynamic@#, FieldSize -> 5] &,
               {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {2}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a possible simpler problem: I just want to enter a string as a control variable in a manipulate. But I cannot get it to work. Here is my last attempt: Clear[string];
Manipulate[string, {string, "a", InputField[Dynamic[string], String]}]

Answer (score 2):

The principal question seems to be how to format matrix input in matrix form.  The rest is not explained clearly enough for me to address and seems extraneous.

*The OP's approach:*

```
Manipulate[value[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], 
 Style["Matrix values", 12, Bold],
 Grid[{
   {Control@{{a, 0}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small},
    Control@{{b, 0}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small}},
   {Control@{{c, 0}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small},
    Control@{{d, 0}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small}}
   }],
 {{e, -10, "x-min"}, -20, 0, 1}, {{f, 10, "x-max"}, 0, 20, 1},
 {{g, -10, "y-min"}, -20, 0, 1}, {{h, 10, "y-max"}, 0, 20, 1},
 {{i, 5, "Solutions"}, 0, 50, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Entering a matrix as a matrix:*  Here, instead of each component of the matrix being its own symbol & variable, I used a single matrix.  Working with this form seems less cumbersome to me, even though it takes a little extra code to get the input to work.  (Irrelevant variables omitted.)

```
Manipulate[
 matrix,
 Style["Matrix values", 12, Bold],
 {{matrix, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}},
  Grid[
    Table[With[{i = i, j = j},
      InputField[Dynamic[matrix[[i, j]]], ImageSize -> Tiny]],
     {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
    ] &}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The use of `With` is explained in "A Good Trick to Know", in the tutorial *Introduction to Dynamic* ([`tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic#2125133640`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640)). It injects the **value** of the symbols into the `Dynamic`; without it, one would just have the symbol itself.