# How to create Dynamic InputField Grid for matrix variable?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I need to make an `InputField` `Grid` change the values of a matrix variable without creating a ton of dummy variables. Minimal example follows as the actual matrix is much larger. This will be used in a UI.

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

However, the `InputField`s are not linked to the values of `m` when referenced with `Indexed`.  The `Grid` that is produced has empty `InputField`s even though `m` has values.

```
Grid@
 Table[InputField[Dynamic[Indexed[m, {r, c}]], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{{r, c}, Dimensions[m]}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When entering values into the `InputFields` they simply disappear and have no effect on `m`.  `m` stays with its original values.

```
Dynamic@m
```

I next tried to `Part` instead of `Indexed` which led to errors and still the values that are entered disappear.

```
Grid@
 Table[InputField[Dynamic[m[[r, c]]], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{{r, c}, Dimensions[m]}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I create an `InputField` `Grid` linked to a matrix variable?  Other control combinations are welcome.  The objective is a GUI to edit the matrix such that the edited matrix can be extracted and used.

Comment: Michael E2 gave an answer you can use [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90084/3066)

Comment: @m_goldberg Arrrhhhh!! The dreaded `With`. That has something to do with the hold attributes of both `Table` and `Dynamic` interacting, correct?

Comment: It has to do with creating a control with a pure function and Mathematica's method for avoiding scoping conflicts in pure functions. See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/3066)